# load an php page into a div on click of li of menu

Tags: jquery, dom, tabs

i have a nav bar which has li items like menu1....menu5 and they are addressed by class. i have 5 php files named as wrap1...wrap5.
i want to load those files in the container of index.php when one of the menu bar li is clicked. I used the load function but to vain.

```
    $('.menu1').click(function(){
       $('#container').load('views/wrap2.php', function() {
       $('#container').fadeIn('slow') ;
   });
});
```

Also in index.php i am including all the necessary pages like top.php , navbar.php , body.php & footer.php. Is that an issue ????

EDIT ----

here's the index.php

```
<?php
   require ('views/top.php') ;
   require ('views/quick.php') ;
   require ('views/navbar.php') ;
   echo '<div id="container">';
   echo '</div>';

   require ('views/footer.php') ;

?>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <a href="views/wrap1.php"><li class="wrap1"> Home &nbsp&nbsp </li></a>
    <a href="views/wrap2.php"><li class="wrap2"> Packages</li></a>
    <a href="views/wrap3.php"><li class="wrap3"> Clients &nbsp </li></a>
    <a href="views/wrap4.php"><li class="wrap4">  Creations</li></a>
    <a href="views/wrap5.php"><li class="wrap5"> Reach Us &nbsp </li></a>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: syntax error: it should be  $('#container').fadeIn('slow') ;

Comment: oops !! sorry for that , even after fixing that error it didn't work. :(

Comment: including top.php or ... is not the error.Can you provide the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tabs li').click(function(){
     $('#container').load('views/'+$(this).attr("class")+'.php', function() {
        $('#container').fadeIn('slow') ;
       });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Here is [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GxY4M/)

Comment: i used it but still not able to get a desired output.

Comment: thnks for you help.. but still not getting anything. Upon clicking it just redirects to that page

Comment: @SaurabhShukla see the edited answer.remove the comment lines in demo.I cannot use live ajax demo on that site.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Don't know what on earth is happening with my script , can't seem to get it work. I'll have to try something else. Appreciated you help

Comment: @SaurabhShukla if this script is not working than the problem with your jquery?which version are you using or is it loaded properly(before code)

Comment: yup. i am using 1.8.2 . i have loaded that library in the head section and the tab script after the </body> tag

Comment: @SaurabhShukla if that isn't the problem than find is ` $('#container')` is available or it's id is unique?

Comment: It worked man ! thanks a lott !! Worked like a charm. Kudos to you man.

Comment: @SaurabhShukla if it helped than you can accept the answer by clicking the right mark below the voting panel